# alert() not working in function

Tags: javascript

Added buttons to my rock paper scissors game, I was having trouble making the alert show up after the userChoice variable changes, so I used eventListeners for that and the winner stopped showing up with the alert, why is this happening? Is there a better way to do this?

I'm a beginner any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>


<script>

function compPlay (){} //picks a random nb and makes it rock paper... 

let userChoice;

function userPlay (){
  btnRock.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    userChoice="rock";
    return userChoice;
  });

  btnPaper.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    userChoice="paper";
    return userChoice;
  });

  btnScissors.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    userChoice="scissors";
    return userChoice;
  });
}

function theGame (compPlay,userPlay) {
  if (compPlay===userPlay) {
    alert("its tied");
  } else if (compPlay === "rock" && userPlay === "scissors") {
    alert("you lose!");
  } else if (compPlay === "scissors" && userPlay === "paper") {
    alert("you lose");
  } else if (compPlay=== "paper" && userPlay === "rock"){
    alert("you lose");
  } else if (compPlay === "scissors" && userPlay === "rock") {
    alert("you win!");
  } else if (compPlay === "paper" && userPlay === "scissors") {
    alert("you win");
  } else if (compPlay=== "rock" && userPlay === "paper"){
    alert("you win");
}
}

theGame(compPlay(),userPlay());

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: `return userChoice;`  A return from an async function has no meaning..

Answer (score 0):

The function call will happen during the load of the script.At that time, the `compPlay` function will return a value whereas the `userPlay` function will create the elements. Thereafter when the button click is happening, the function will not even be called.

Edit:For your info..This is one way to do it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>


<script>
function compPlay (){

  let comChoice= Math.random();
  console.log(comChoice);
  if (comChoice<=0.33){
    comChoice= "rock";
  } else if (comChoice<=0.66){
    comChoice= "scissors";
  } else {
    comChoice= "paper";
  }
  userPlay(comChoice);
  }

let userChoice;

function userPlay (comChoice){//Function for user's click comparison with computer's option

  let btnRock = document.createElement("button");
  let tRock = document.createTextNode("Rock");
  btnRock.appendChild(tRock);
  document.body.appendChild(btnRock);
  btnRock.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    userChoice="rock";
    theGame(comChoice,userChoice);//Main function call to decide the winner
  });


  let btnPaper = document.createElement("button");
  let tPaper = document.createTextNode("Paper");
  btnPaper.appendChild(tPaper);
  document.body.appendChild(btnPaper);
  btnPaper.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    userChoice="paper";
    theGame(comChoice,userChoice);
  });

  let btnScissors = document.createElement("button");
  let tScissors = document.createTextNode("Scissors");
  btnScissors.appendChild(tScissors);
  document.body.appendChild(btnScissors);
  btnScissors.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    userChoice="scissors";
    theGame(comChoice,userChoice);
  });
}

function theGame (compPlay,userPlay) {
  if (compPlay===userPlay) {
    alert("its tied");
  } else if (compPlay === "rock" && userPlay === "scissors") {
    alert("you lose!");
  } else if (compPlay === "scissors" && userPlay === "paper") {
    alert("you lose");
  } else if (compPlay=== "paper" && userPlay === "rock"){
    alert("you lose");
  } else if (compPlay === "scissors" && userPlay === "rock") {
    alert("you win!");
  } else if (compPlay === "paper" && userPlay === "scissors") {
    alert("you win");
  } else if (compPlay=== "rock" && userPlay === "paper"){
    alert("you win");
}
}
compPlay();//Basic initialising function call 

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify and show me how it should be done please?

Comment: @AdrianAlvarez answer wont work because the comchoice was not getting passed to the userPlay function

Answer (score 0):

You could call the game function when you click on a button

```
btnScissors.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
userChoice="scissors";
theGame(comChoice,userChoice);
});
```

EDIT:
I forgot to said that in order to work  to you should change your comChoice to a Global variable.Thanks @Krisna Prashatt